# How to take mysql backup of remote instance using salt state file?

Tags: salt-cloud

I have created a state file in master ,when i am trying to run the state file to take the backup of mysql database of minion from master i am unable to create the backup file.

Comment: What do you mean by _unable to create the backup file_?